# Is "got" okay to replace "became" in "I strayed a few blocks in the wrong direction and became hopelessly lost"?

Tags: word-difference

Is it okay to use **got** instead of **became** in the sentence below?

> I strayed a few blocks in the wrong direction and **became** hopelessly lost.

In the past, I regarded **become + adjective/past participle structure** and **get + adjective/past participle structure** as almost the same, but in so many cases I was wrong in fact. The difference between the two usages is pretty hard to define exactly for me who is not a native English speaker. I am trying to find it out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes they can be interchanged but each has different nuances. "became" emphasises the progressive nature of getting lost and "got" the end result. Having used "strayed a few blocks" it does lend itself more to a gradual "becoming" lost.